# Java regex dot does not match the real dot character (.)

Tags: java, regex

I'm practicing to parse XML.

My sentence is

```
<SINGER>I.O.I</SINGER> came back on <MONTH>May</MONTH> 4, <YEAR>2016</YEAR>.
```

I used both

```
Pattern.compile("<[^/^>.]+>[^<^>.]+</[^>.]+>");
```

and

```
Pattern.compile("<[^/^>.]+>[^<^>\\..]+</[^>.]+>");
```

However, the regexes could not match

`<SINGER>I.O.I</SINGER>`

I think my regexes act weird because of those dots since they could match

`<SINGER>I-O-I</SINGER>`

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Even if this is practice, you should note that this is not *valid* xml (so it's a bad practice, if your goal is to parse real XML), and you shouldn't use regex to parse a markup language (XML, HTML, XHTML, *ML)

Comment: @BackSlash Why isn't it valid XML?

Comment: If you're processing XML you should use XML technologies to do it, such as an XML parser, XPath and XSLT. Regular expressions are not adequate to XML in general.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi If I remember correctly, you shouldn't be able to put both text and elements inside another element in XML, unless you define your own schema which allows that. But I might be wrong. But the most important thing is second one: don't use regex to parse markup languages. Use a parser, or if you want to learn how to manually parse XML do some research and learn how to do it properly (without regexes)

Comment: @Backslash It isn't a valid XML *document*, because there is no enclosing element. But you aren't obliged to define a schema.

Comment: @EJP Ah, you mean the entire sentence?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'the entire sentence'. I meant what I said, no more, no less. In 30 years on the Internet and its predecessors I have observed that the answer to 'so you mean ...' is invariably 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `<[^/^>.]+>[^<^>.]+</[^>.]+>` means:

1. `<`
2. One or more characters except `/` `^` `>` and `.`
3. `>`
4. One or more characters except `<` `^` `>` `.`
5. `</`
6. One or more characters except `>` `.`
7. `>`

So it won't match `<SINGER>I.O.I</SINGER>`

You probably want something like `<[^>]+>[^<]*</[^>]+>` as a quick-and-dirty way to extract data from an XML tag.

Then you need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` properly:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^>]+>([^<]*)</[^>]+>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<SINGER>I.O.I</SINGER> came back on <MONTH>May</MONTH> 4, <YEAR>2016</YEAR>.");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Will print:

```
I.O.I
May
2016
```

Comment: Looks like OP thought that `^/^>.` means "everything, except `/` and `>`.

Comment: That could be it, yeah

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dot or other characters with a special meaning in regexes to be a normal character, you have to escape it with a backslash. Since regexes in Java are normal Java strings, you need to escape the backslash itself, so you need two backslashes e.g. `\\.`

Comment: I think I did it in my second regex.

Comment: Shouldn't regex . matches the real dot character (.)?

Comment: For that itself u have to you use \\